# How to find network card details on RHEL machines

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface, ethernet, dmidecode

Is it possible to find out the details about Linux cards?

For example we tried:

```
dmidecode | grep -i network
                Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Port Type: Network Port
        Port Type: Network Port
        Port Type: Network Port
        Port Type: Network Port
# dmidecode | grep -i eth
        Type: Ethernet
        Type: Ethernet
        Type: Ethernet
        Type: Ethernet
```

This details doesn't say anything about the network cards and performance etc.

Any advice about tools that can give these details about network cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For getting the brand/model of the network card, usually you run:

```
$ lspci | grep -i Ethernet
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
```

Or for getting more detail of the NIC(s):

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:25:4d:0e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.5.143 latency=0 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

Grepping `dmesg` for the network device might also help:

```
$ dmesg | grep eth0
[    1.635942] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: (PCI:66MHz:32-bit) 00:0c:29:25:4d:0e
[    1.635960] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    3.736090] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[    3.742639] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
```

As for `dmidecode`, `dmidecode -t baseboard` might show information about NICs that are built-in in the motherboard.

PS As for Unix SE questions, when dealing with hardware questions, a full `lscpi` output is probably more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ethtool` which give you more info about your card, and also control network driver and hardware settings.

e.g:

```bsh
# ethtool enp0s31f6 

Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x0000ffff (65535)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol 0x8000
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: can you please give your smart opinion about the post - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585970/networking-ethtool-display-different-configuration-between-interface-on-differ